# Detecting task switching in android lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-lifecycle

Our app has its own password screen that show ups when the app comes from background. It works fine on pre-5.0. On lollipop it works fine when clicking the home button but if I use the "switch app" button it doesn't. up until now I used this code

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {    
    isWindowFocused = hasFocus;    
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (!isWindowFocused) {
        isAppInBg = true;
    }       
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    if (isAppInBg) {
        isAppInBg = false;
        App.showPin = true;
    }
    super.onStart();
}
```

When debugging I found out that on pre-5.0 devices onWindowFocusChanged returns false when switching apps while 5.0 devices return true (and thus not setting isAppInBg to true). Maybe I will feel really dumb when this is answered but for the past few hours I wasn't able to find a solution. thanks...